# Android l Room peristence l Entries of curent week

Tags: java, android, sql, datetime, android-room

I have an application that let users input data and i want to store  the time of their input and then filter all input based on day/week/month.
Cant figure out how would i do that especially filterind data of introduced this week .

Would be much appreciated any help .

Kind regards.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: What's the table structure? Seems like a simple answer this one.

Comment: Its a simple database  ,it got id,text,and a field for integer ,doesnt have field for storing the time yet

Comment: Sorry, this question is both too broad and too vague for Stack Overflow. You will need to conduct your own research into possibilities (there are quite some).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table structure is like this:

```
create table log (
  id int,
  text varchar(200),
  value int,
  recorded_at datetime
);
```

Then, for example in MySQL, to find the records from the last two weeks:

```
select * from log 
  where recorded_at > now() - interval 2 week;
```